# Mysql - Explain key is null

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, explain

In my table Emails

```
mysql> explain select * from Emails where email_id IN  (2029000006126024, 2029000004564319, 2029000000692079, 2029000004564202);
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys                          | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Emails        | NULL       | ALL  | Emails_FK1_IDX,Emails_IDX2             | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 785984 |    57.70 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

and already indexes also created for the column "email_id",but query is running for full table.

and create table query is

```
CREATE TABLE `Emails` (
`EMAIL_REPORT_ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
`CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
`SENT_DATE` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
`EMAIL_ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
`BOUNCE` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`BOUNCED_DATE` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
`SPAM` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`OPT_OUT` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`IGNORED` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`CMP_CONTENT_ID` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
`RESTRICT` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`TIME_ZONE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`GMT_DEVIATION` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`CMP_COMMENTS_COUNT` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`IGNORED_BY_TRAP` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`EMAIL_REPORT_ID`),
KEY `Emails_FK1_IDX` (`CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_ID`),
KEY `Emails_FK2_IDX` (`CONTACT_ID`),
KEY `Emails_FK3_IDX` (`RECIPIENT_SELECTION_ID`),
KEY `Emails_FK4_IDX` (`CMP_CONTENT_ID`),
KEY `Emails_IDX1` (`SENT_DATE`),
KEY `Emails_IDX2` (`CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_ID`),
KEY `Emails_IDX3` (`EMAIL_REPORT_ID`,`CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Experts please how to fix this.

Comment: Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Emails`

Comment: I didn't post full query, any other info?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: Please find my question now.

Comment: Huh?  The query refers to `email_id`, but that column does not exist in the table??

Comment: sry now check this.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will not use the index if it estimates that the values you search for would probably match much of the table.

The specific threshold is not documented, but in my experience when your query matches approximately 20% of the table, and the optimizer can infer this from the query logic, it decides that it's more effective to do a table-scan and filter out rows it examines than to use an index.

If you disagree, you can use the [`FORCE INDEX` hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to tell the optimizer that a table-scan is too costly and it should prefer to use an index if there's an applicable index.

Comment: but every time I will add force index query, i don't want this

Comment: @Aaryan - What percent of the rows actually match that list of email_ids?

Comment: 50 percent of rows

Comment: @Aaryan, if you don't want to use an index hint, then you must accept the optimizer's plan. You only get those two choices! :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin agree with optimizer's plan, How to optimize it

Comment: Your query matches over 50% of the table, so approximately 400,000 rows. That's going to take some time to read and return to the application. To get this to run faster, get a more powerful computer!